# Launch link in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

i would like to launch custom dynamic links..

i have getter which load string text from database, this string text is user input with them IG username
**bio is IG username, exsample @instagram**

```
 String getBio(String bio) {
if (widget.isMyProfile) {
  return bio;
} else if (bio == "") {
  return "";
} else {
  return bio;
}
```

}

i want to have static link "**[https://instagram.com/**;"](https://instagram.com/**;%22) where end of link will be dynamic instagram user name
example:  'https://instagram.com/instagram';

```
_launchURLIG() async {
const url = 'https://instagram.com/';
if (await canLaunch(url)) {
  await launch(url);
} else {
  throw 'Could not launch $url';
}
```

}

=====
something like this.     **https://instagram.com' + getBio**

```
_launchURLIG() async {
const url = 'https://instagram.com' + getBio ;
if (await canLaunch(url)) {
  await launch(url);
} else {
  throw 'Could not launch $url';
}
```

}

Comment: What will it be your question? As your code has a proper logic (except that you need to add a slash "/" at the end of instagram.com, for example. How are you planning to get the info from your Db? Just pass the variable over a parameter for _launchURLIG

Comment: hello @MarianoZorrilla, I have this up function where i get info for DB ( getBio() ), and i creted button to app, where on press need to open user profiles in instagram..   i created the second function (_launchURLIG) for this..
But now i need to load diferent user profiles where end of the link in function( _launchURLIG) will be dynamic username, which i get from database.. Hope you understand me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should past profile as a parameter to your function

```
_launchURLIG(String userId) async {
String url = 'https://instagram.com/' + userId ;
if (await canLaunch(url)) {
  await launch(url);
} else {
  throw 'Could not launch $url';
}
```

Comment: it have error on line "String url = 'https://instagram.com/' + userId ;"

 "userId" in my case "getBio"

Comment: could you share the error? saying that it has error doesn't help at all

Comment: There is pic with error, i uploaded now

Comment: `canLaunch` and `launch` is deprecated and when I change it to `canLaunchUrl` : said The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'. @CarlosSandoval can please update your answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need this package to run link:
https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher